# How to convert ASCII character to decimal number in Android?

Tags: java, android, ascii, decimal

I'm working on an Android app. I have a TextView which contains an ASCII character. This character changes every 2 hours. I need to be able to read this character and convert it to decimal number, and then write it to an another TextView. So let's say the character is "[" and it's decimal value is 91. 2 hours later this character changes to "U" and it's decimal value is 85.

Can anyone help me what kind of code should I use in my app to be able to convert ASCII character to decimal number?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Typecast character to int, you will get the Unicode code point for that character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get chars in loop like that :

```
char x;
int[] t = new int[string.length];
for(int i = 0; i < string.length; i++)
{
x = string.charAt(i);
int z = (int) x;
t[i] = z;
}
```

Comment: Do you assume `string` to be a `String[]` array? If yes, your code won't even compile.

Answer (score 2):

Use this if your String has a length of 1:

```
char c = yourString.charAt(0);
int decVal = (int) c;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "123";
int size = str.length();
int [] arr = new int[size];

for(int i =0; i<size;i++) {
    arr[i] = Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(i));
}

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(arr[i]);
}
```

output:

> 123

Simple way is

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(str); // parsing
```